# Singular values of a matrix after scaling

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a complex matrix $A$ and diagonal matrix $D$ with no zero elements on its diagonal, it is well-known that $A$ and $DAD^{-1}$ has the same eigenvalues, however not the same singular values.

My question is, how far apart can the singular values be? 
Specifically, consider a stochastic matrix $A$ of dimension $n$ with eigenvalues $|\lambda_1| \ge |\lambda_{2}| \ge \ldots \ge |\lambda_n|$
such that $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $|\lambda_{2}| < 1$. Denote its singular values by $\sigma_{1} \ge \sigma_{2} \ge \ldots \ge \sigma_{n}$, and we know that $\sigma_{1} = 1$ if $A$ is doubly stochastic and $\sigma_{1} > 1$ otherwise. Can one obtain a non-trivial upper bound on $\sigma_{2}(DAD^{-1})$? (I know that a lower bound can be achieved by majorization). In other words, might it be that $\sigma_{2}(DAD^{-1})=\sigma_{1}(DAD^{-1})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singular values of $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ are $1,1$.

Let $D = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ where $\alpha > 0$, then $B = D A D^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \alpha \\ \dfrac{1}{\alpha} & 0\end{pmatrix}.$

Since $B^TB=\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{1}{\alpha^2} & 0\\ 0 & \alpha^2 \end{pmatrix}$ and so the singular values of $B = DAD^{-1}$ are $\dfrac{1}{\alpha}$ and $\alpha$ respectively. We can make the largest singular value of $B$ as large as we wish by letting $\alpha \to 0^+$ and the gap between the singular values also tends to $\infty.$